# how to convert byte array to String in vb6

Tags: string, vb6, arrays

I want to convert byte array to String in vb6 . That is why , I am using the following code :

```
ReDim g_Template(dwLen) As Byte
    i = 0
    Do While Len(m_strTemplate) > 0
        iPos = InStr(1, m_strTemplate, "$")
        If (iPos > 0) Then
            g_Template(i) = Mid(m_strTemplate, 1, iPos - 1)
            m_strTemplate = Right(m_strTemplate, Len(m_strTemplate) - iPos)
            i = i + 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Dim FingerData As String
    Dim iPos1 As Integer
    FingerData = StrConv(g_Template, vbUnicode)
    iPos1 = InStr(FingerData, Chr(0))
    If iPos1 > 0 Then FingerData = Left(FingerData, iPos1 - 1)
```

But the conversion does not return the right String data . Where is the error ? How can I convert the byte data to String in vb6 ?

Comment: Your code makes no sense when you place it with your question. What are you trying to do with the loop? What is `m_strTemplate` and why are you searching for"$"?

Comment: If you're trying to load a byte array to test it's probably easier and less error prone than your code if you just read a text file directly into a byte array using binary access mode.

Comment: try `FingerData = StrConv(g_Template, vbFromUnicode)`